# Why doesn't Ubuntu show my wireless device after updating the kernel?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, wireless-networking

After an kernel update Ubuntu doesn't show my wireless device. How can I fix this?

I checked the syslogs and it says the following:

```
2010-02-16 19:25:39,913 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
2010-02-16 19:25:39,940 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2010-02-16 19:25:46,066 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2010-02-16 19:25:46,086 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2010-02-16 19:25:46,162 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2010-02-16 19:35:05,451 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2010-02-16 19:35:05,480 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2010-02-16 19:35:05,506 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2010-02-16 19:35:12,496 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2010-02-16 19:35:19,870 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
2010-02-16 19:35:23,398 WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl

2010-02-16 19:35:23,399 WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
2010-02-16 19:35:23,432 DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted
```

Comment: What hardware are you using and what specific update did you apply?

Comment: I am on Lenovo G430. It has Broadcom Wireless Device.

Comment: I have tried lspci. It shows hardware. But no interface on ifconfig.

Comment: Are you running ifconfig -a?

Comment: Have a look in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf (and similar files) to see why b43 is blacklisted - AFAIK it's the latest broadcom driver. Also you might like to run jockey and see if it suggests any better drivers for your wireless card.